# How to run code after UIView transitionWithView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to run a block of code after an animation is completed but the compiler shows the following error : "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(void)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(BOOL)'"

Here is my code, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, please help, thanks.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom //change to whatever animation you like
                animations:^ {
                    [self.view addSubview:myImageView1];
                    [self.view addSubview:myImageView2];
                }
                completion:^ {
                    NSLog(@"Animations completed.");
                    // do something...
                }];
```

Answer (score 14):

You just have the wrong block type :) It needs a block like below. The key being `^(BOOL finished) {...}`

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom //change to whatever animation you like
                animations:^ {
                    [self.view addSubview:myImageView1];
                    [self.view addSubview:myImageView2];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    if (finished) {
                        // Successful
                    }
                    NSLog(@"Animations completed.");
                    // do something...
                }];
```